# System.Net.Http.HttpClient 4 Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am not able to do a Post or Delete operation from a WPF Application using a HttpClient Object.
But I can do a Get and GetById(string id) operations using HttpClient.

The namespace of HttpClient is System.Net.Http. [**I tried to use a Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient, but I could not add this dll as reference in the WPF Project. This httpclient dll has to download from the internet.**]

Here is the code for a Delete Operation. Below code is in the click eventhandler of WPF Button.

```
   public void DeleteByID(string id)
    {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  //system.net.http          
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44390/");             
      var url = "api/Player/" + id;
    
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.DeleteAsync(url).Result; **// ERROR here**

      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("User Deleted");                
      }
      else
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Code");
      }
   }
```

Its corresponding Web Api HttpDelete method is shown below :

```
   public class PlayerController : ApiController
      {
        SqlConnection con = new 
             SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = null;

       [HttpDelete]
       public bool DeleteByID(string id)
       {
          bool isdeleted = false;
        
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "delete from tbl_Player where ID = '" + id + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (res > 0)
            {
                isdeleted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isdeleted = false;                   
            }
            con.Close();
            return isdeleted;
        }
        catch
        {
            return isdeleted;
        }            
     }

     [HttpGet]
    public DataTable Get()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_Player";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt.TableName = "tbl_Player";
            adp.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return dt;
    }
 }
```

And my Player class is shown below :

```
  public class Player
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  }
```

In the SQLServer, table definition is as shown below.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Player](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Age] [int] NULL,
  [Place] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Player] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Below is the working code for a Get Operation and its web api method is mentioned in controller class above.

```
   public void GetData()
     {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44390/");
        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Player").Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var players = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Player>>().Result;
            dgPlayers.ItemsSource = players; // dgPlayers is the datagrid in WPF Window.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Code");
        }
    }
```

Actually I am getting 4 types of errors. The details of the error is mentioned below :

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'

Error No.1 : HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Error No.2 : WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Error No.3 : IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Error No.4 : SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I tried all ways to get it resolved. I used async and await also. When I used async and await, there is no error thrown, it is stuck there - the UI becomes not responsive. Error is throwing in the DeleteById method. The call didnt come to the web api Delete web method.

please help me to resolve this issue.

thanks

Comment: Can you show the controller action pls?

Comment: @Serge updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: *Don't* block asynchronous calls. Make `DeleteByID` asynchronous and use `await client.DeleteAsync(url);` . Post the *actual, full exception text* not just parts of it. The parts you posted suggest the *server* crashed.

Comment: The server action is wide open to SQL injection attacks. If `ID` contains eg `1'; drop table tbl;-` your code will drop the table. That `catch` will hide any errors that occur after that. The fact that the server crashes though suggests that an exception is thrown before that action, perhaps in the controller's constructor. You should add proper exception handling and logging instead of hiding errors, otherwise it's almost impossible to identify problems

Comment: @Serge I have eloborated the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have elaborated the question, please look at it.

Comment: I solved this issue. Now it is working well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue and my code is running fine without any error.
The issue was very simple.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44390/");
```

I was using "http" instead of "https" in Uri. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

fix your code, remove connection close

```
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.CommandText = $"delete from tbl where ID = '{id}'";
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
            int res = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            con.Close();                
        }
        catch
        {
            
        }            
    }
```

and remember about sql script injection. Use a parameter instead of a string value.

Comment: I checked again as per your suggestion. Actually before reaching HttpDelete method, the error throws at HttpResponseMessage response = client.DeleteAsync(url).Result; // error here

Comment: @Johnny Do you know how to use a Postman? Try to test using http://localhost:44390/api/Player/ + id and delete method.